# How to save rabbitMQ messages to csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq

I am new to rabbitMQ and I used the "Hello world" tutorial for python on rabbitMQ page. Is is somehow possible to store messages to CSV file? I want to store messages which contain substring test.

I have a send.py

```
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
    pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!')
selections = ['test-1223', '1test', 'something', 'earth']
substring = 'test'
for market in selections:
    if substring in market:
        print(market)
connection.close()
```

and receive.py

```
import pika, sys, os

def main():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
    channel = connection.channel()

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback, auto_ack=True)

    print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
    channel.start_consuming()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you want to store incoming messages or outgoing?

Comment: received messages, so in my example would be test-1223' and 1test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with csv using the `csv` module. like

```
import csv

if "test" in body:
    with open('messages.csv', mode='a') as msg_file:
        msg_writer = csv.writer(msg_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        msg_writer.writerow([body])
```

Comment: I would like to save received messages not what is sent. That if part will already be solved on sent part, so the receiver should already get messages with string test.

Comment: use the snippet where you received your message. before/after this line ```print(" [x] Received %r" % body)```

Comment: Ah yes, it works, only thing I had to change was msg_writer.writerow([body])

Comment: @Jerry glad it worked and sorry for my mistake. I have fixed it. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @mursalin my incoming messages are in json format. Could you please let me know how to save the messages into a json file